# How to check if value exist in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let test = {fruit: ["apple", "pair", "cow2"],
            friend: ["chair", "car", "cow"]}
const me = "cow"
if （find）{do something}
```

How do i check if "cow" exist in in array? i want to check if is in fruit, if not then search into next one (which is in friend)

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: `const contains = (o, s) => [].concat(...Object.values(o)).includes(s)`